# Map Proximity - Modify markers

Tags: 7, google-maps

I want to build a map that has multiple control selectors above the map. When one icon is selected, it prints the relevant markers all over the globe on the map.

If one of the control selectors appears at any one location it just shows one marker, but if two or more different control selectors are clicked on and they share the same location, the marker is modified and expands.

In essence this is something "like a heatmap" function, but not quite.

Anyone had a similar project that can relate and perhaps set me on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it. That project page also includes various screenshots.